# What protocol use the password in the file "hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml" in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, password-encryption

I really want to know what protocol Jenkins uses to encrypt passwords stored in the file "hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml". I'm creating new projects from another system (private software) and these are all imported in Jenkins without using the native interface. I want to change the file every time a user updates their credentials SVN

I have installed the following plugin: "Subversion Plugin"

**EDIT**

I solved my doubt analyzing the source code and the protocol is "AES".